# Is there a way to do an If Then statement in the join clause

Tags: sql, left-join, amazon-redshift, where-clause, full-outer-join

I have two tables, spend and bookings, that I'm trying to do a full join on. Due to the nature of the tables (not all bookings have spend, and not all spend has a booking_id, and sometimes the wrong booking_id gets assigned), I'd like to do a conditional statement in the join clause.

```
select bk.booking_id, bk.company_id, bk.event_id, bk.total_amount_booked, sp.spend
from 
(select booking_id, company_id, event_id, booked_rate, total_amount_booked
from bookings) bk
full join
(select booking_id, company_id, event_id, normalized_spend, spend
from spend) sp
on (bk.booking_id = sp.booking_id and bk.booked_rate = sp.normalized_spend)
or (bk.company_id = sp.company_id and bk.event_id = sp.event_id);
```

Basically, if the booking_id matches and the normalized spend matches the booked_rate, then join on that condition.
If not, join on company_id and event_id.

However, doing this query returns

`FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable join conditions;`

Is there a better way to do this?
Using Redshift

Comment: Aside - RedShift does not run on PostgreSQL. It is a distinct DBMS that originated with an earlier Postgres dialect.

Comment: DataGrip says I'm running PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.19097. I'm assuming that it's an older version of Postgres, but there are some functions you can't do on Redshift that you can do on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of pain, but you could emulate the `full` join with two `left joins` and `union all`:

```
select bk.booking_id, bk.company_id, bk.event_id, bk.total_amount_booked, sp.spend
from bookings bk
left join spend sp
    on (bk.booking_id = sp.booking_id and bk.booked_rate = sp.normalized_spend)
    or (bk.company_id = sp.company_id and bk.event_id = sp.event_id)
union all
select bk.booking_id, bk.company_id, bk.event_id, bk.total_amount_booked, sp.spend
from spend sp
left join bookings bk
    on (bk.booking_id = sp.booking_id and bk.booked_rate = sp.normalized_spend)
    or (bk.company_id = sp.company_id and bk.event_id = sp.event_id)
where bk.booking_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using CASE statement, something like

```
...ON CASE WHEN (bk.booking_id = sp.booking_id and bk.booked_rate = sp.normalized_spend)
          THEN (bk.booking_id = sp.booking_id and bk.booked_rate = sp.normalized_spend)
         WHEN (bk.company_id = sp.company_id and bk.event_id = sp.event_id) 
          THEN (bk.company_id = sp.company_id and bk.event_id = sp.event_id)
    END
```

Comment: This gives the same "FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable join conditions" error